# Не получается настроить add_rewrite_rule() - WordPress

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, wordpress

У меня есть вот такой url `http://nightlifer.new-norm.pro/test/apiBaseClass/getHeaders/?id="3,5"&page=1`.

Хочу чтобы запрос обрабатывался в вот таком виде `http://nightlifer.new-norm.pro/test/?apiBaseClass.getHeaders={"id":[3,5],"page":1}`.

Пробовал вот так:

```
add_action('init', 'do_rewrite');

function do_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?id=$ids&page=$page', 'test/?$matches[1].$matches[2]={"id":$ids,"page":$page}', 'top' );  
}
```

В итоге у меня ничего не вышло...

Answer (score 2):

1) Строка (`http://nightlifer.new-norm.pro/test/apiBaseClass/getHeaders/?id="3,5"&page=1`) не начинается со слово 'test' а в синтаксисе регулярных выражений знак `^` означает начало строки, то есть искомое выражение должно было находиться в начале строки.

2) Всегда в регулярных выражениях надо Экранировать специальные символы,
то есть

```
`^test/([^/]*)/([^/]*)` надо заменить на `^test\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)`
```

Пример отдельной экранировки символа в регулярном вырожении `/` -> `\/`
 То есть обратный слеш выводит следующий символ так как он есть и он не 
 применяется как специальный символ.

**Решение вашего вопроса:**

```
function do_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '\/test\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/?id=$ids&page=$page', 'test/?$matches[1].$matches[2]={"id":$ids,"page":$page}', 'top' );  
}
```

Регулярка работает по следующему принцыпу:

ищет в строке `/test/` а после этого должно обязательно быт два выражения отделенные по символу `/`, но если у вас после определенного выражения будет больше или меньше двух выражений то надо будет уточнить детали, и я обновлю ответ.

**[RegExr: Обучение, сборка и тестирование RegEx](http://regexr.com/)**

Удачи!